# Dag example pet failed to insert and getbirth

Tags: sql, postgresql, airflow

I am new to `airflow`. I set up everything according to official documentation. I use `pet example DAG`, nevertheless when i look into `DAG` log it shows me following errors:

**First error** comming from `populate_pet_table`

```
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: "Maxy"
LINE 2:             INSERT INTO pet VALUES ('Maxy', 'Dog', '2018-07-...
```

**Second error** comming from `get_birth_date`

```
BETWEEN SYMMETRIC 2020-01-01 AND 2020-12-31;


HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What is wrong there? This is really official example so to me should work fine. This is the dag's code:

```
import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator

# create_pet_table, populate_pet_table, get_all_pets, and get_birth_date are examples of tasks created by
# instantiating the Postgres Operator

with DAG(
    dag_id="postgres_operator_dag",
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 2),
    schedule_interval="@once",
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    create_pet_table = PostgresOperator(
        task_id="create_pet_table",
        postgres_conn_id="postgres_default",
        sql="""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pet (
            pet_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
            pet_type VARCHAR NOT NULL,
            birth_date DATE NOT NULL,
            OWNER VARCHAR NOT NULL);
          """,
    )
    populate_pet_table = PostgresOperator(
        task_id="populate_pet_table",
        postgres_conn_id="postgres_default",
        sql="""
            INSERT INTO pet VALUES ( 'Max', 'Dog', '2018-07-05', 'Jane');
            INSERT INTO pet VALUES ( 'Susie', 'Cat', '2019-05-01', 'Phil');
            INSERT INTO pet VALUES ( 'Lester', 'Hamster', '2020-06-23', 'Lily');
            INSERT INTO pet VALUES ( 'Quincy', 'Parrot', '2013-08-11', 'Anne');
            """,
    )
    get_all_pets = PostgresOperator(
        task_id="get_all_pets", postgres_conn_id="postgres_default", sql="SELECT * FROM pet;"
    )
    get_birth_date = PostgresOperator(
        task_id="get_birth_date",
        postgres_conn_id="postgres_default",
        sql="""
            SELECT * FROM pet
            WHERE birth_date
            BETWEEN SYMMETRIC {{ params.begin_date }} AND {{ params.end_date }};
            """,
        params={'begin_date': '2020-01-01', 'end_date': '2020-12-31'},
    )

    create_pet_table >> populate_pet_table >> get_all_pets >> get_birth_date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be an error with the SQL itself.

Change:

```
INSERT INTO pet VALUES ( 'Max', 'Dog', '2018-07-05', 'Jane');
INSERT INTO pet VALUES ( 'Susie', 'Cat', '2019-05-01', 'Phil');
INSERT INTO pet VALUES ( 'Lester', 'Hamster', '2020-06-23', 'Lily');
INSERT INTO pet VALUES ( 'Quincy', 'Parrot', '2013-08-11', 'Anne');
```

To:

```
INSERT INTO pet (name, pet_type, birth_date, OWNER) VALUES ( 'Max', 'Dog', '2018-07-05', 'Jane');
INSERT INTO pet (name, pet_type, birth_date, OWNER) VALUES ( 'Susie', 'Cat', '2019-05-01', 'Phil');
INSERT INTO pet (name, pet_type, birth_date, OWNER) VALUES ( 'Lester', 'Hamster', '2020-06-23', 'Lily');
INSERT INTO pet (name, pet_type, birth_date, OWNER) VALUES ( 'Quincy', 'Parrot', '2013-08-11', 'Anne');
```

For the second issue you need to change

```
BETWEEN SYMMETRIC {{ params.begin_date }} AND {{ params.end_date }};
```

to:

```
BETWEEN SYMMETRIC DATE '{{ params.begin_date }}' AND DATE '{{ params.end_date }}';
```

and it will work fine.
Example from [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4eb282/1)

I raised a [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/18236) to fix the issue.

Comment: seems like it fixed first error what about second one?

Comment: Yes plz let origin know about issue here as now all works. P.S Can u tell me if i dont want to run one of these tasks howe can i do so? I tried remove (get_birth_date ) so i have now:  create_pet_table >> populate_pet_table >> get_all_pets but dag's log shows it still runs :O